# Anchor tag is not working on IE11 though it works on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, popup, anchor, href

Below is my code to display the message "....Click here...." but clicking on it in IE 11.0.9 does nothing however it forms the link i.e. right click and open in a new tab opens the link fine. also it works fine in google chrome

```
<div id='alrt'></div>

function onSubmit()
{ 
            var strPN =document.getElementById("PN").value;
            var url = "ORKUT.COM";
            document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='downloading...'; 
            setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='';},12000);
            var left = (screen.width/2)-(550/2);
            var top = (screen.height/2)-(550/2);
            popupWindow = window.open (url, 'newWindow', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+550+', height='+550+', top='+top+', left='+left);     
            popupWindow.focus(); 
            document.onmousedown = focusPopup; 
            document.onkeyup = focusPopup; 
            document.onmousemove = focusPopup;
            setTimeout(function () { popupWindow.close();}, 35000);
            document.onmousemove = checkWin;
}

function checkWin() {
if(popupWindow.closed)
{
document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='<strong>If download is not successful,<a href="http://ABC/Home/DownloadDocPage"> Click here</a> to download </strong>';
}
}
```

Comment: Uncheck "Enable Protected Mode" in internet options and try again.

Comment: 'Enable Enhanced protected mode ' is already unchecked